# Set data attribute as unique with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, slider, carousel

What I have working so far is this:

```
$(".photoWrapper img").attr("data-item", "0");
```

I'm able to assign a value to the element I'm selecting; what I can't do is have 2-500 images that have a value of 2-500.  Second image would have a value of 2, third would have 3, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What slider or carousel are you using? What code are you using to loop the different slides, etc. A little more info please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your question very poorly.

I'm guessing you just want a data-item number that counts upwards, so just use a for loop and loop through all the images you want to assign the data-item to.

```
var images = $(".photoWrapper img");
for( var i=0; i<images.length; i++ ) {
    $(images[i]).attr('data-item', i);
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/38ot3evg/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".photoWrapper img").attr("data-item", function(i) {
   return i;
});
alert( $('.photoWrapper img:eq(3)').data('item') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photoWrapper">
  <img src="sample.jpg"/>
  <img src="sample.jpg"/>
  <img src="sample.jpg"/>
  <img src="sample.jpg"/>
  <img src="sample.jpg"/>
  <img src="sample.jpg"/>
  <img src="sample.jpg"/>
</div>
```